# Bash script to remove some keywords in a txt file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xargs

i am not familiar with bash script, after some research, i found some hints but still need your effort.

Given i have a **resources.txt**, contains

```
a
b
c
d
```

and a **whitelist.txt** file, contains

```
c
d
```

I would like to remove all items that exactly match from whitelist file to resource file.
so the expected output is

```
a
b
```

Expect c and d is removed because they are in whitelist file.

I have created below script to read it, but don't know how to replace each one by one to resource file.

```sh
# read the whitelist file
echo whitelist.txt | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s\n",$i}

# replace item in resource file
awk '{sub(/c/,""); print}' resources.txt
```

Your help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Assuming the files are sorted, `comm -23 resources.txt whitelist.txt`

Comment: @Shawn because the list will be dynamic, so using predefined / hardcode index is not a ready-to-go solution :( , btw, thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use this grep:

```
grep -Fvxf whitelist.txt resources.txt
```

- `-F` fixed/literal strings (no regex)
- `-f FILE` get patterns from FILE
- `-x` match the whole line
- `-v` print lines which *don't* match
- This grep is POSIX

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can use

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' whitelist.txt resources.txt
```

In parts

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                       # Only for the first file (whitelist.txt)
  a[$0]                        # Set the value of the whole line as a key in a
  next                         # Go to the next record
}
!($0 in a)                     # Print the line if the value of `$0` does not exists as array index in a
' whitelist.txt resources.txt
```

Output

```
a
b
```